# How can I get the lines that were covered by a particular test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

I was trying to get all the lines that a test case covered. For instance,

```
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilderAppendInsertTest.testAppendFixedWidthPadLeft(org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilderAppendInsertTest)
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:appendFixedWidthPadLeft:1188
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:appendFixedWidthPadLeft:1191
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:appendFixedWidthPadLeft:1194
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:appendFixedWidthPadLeft:1185
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:clear:288
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:clear:287
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:<init>:111
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:<init>:112
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:setNullText:171
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilder:setNullText:172
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilderAppendInsertTest:<init>:56
org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrBuilderAppendInsertTest:<init>:55
```

here `testAppendFixedWidthPadLeft` covered the lines of `StrBuilder` class's `appendFixedWidthPadLeft` method's lines 1188, 1191, 1194, and so on. So I am trying to get this information in a text file. Can anyone suggest me something? I tried Cobertura and Jacoco. But couldn't get anything like that. Thanks.

I tried Cobertura, Jacoco, Gzoltar.